# Serial Fields in Informix for ORM framework

Tags: sql, informix

We use a VERY old version of Informix (SE). I am trying to make an ORM type framework in C# to handle CRUD procedures. I am having a hard time trying to come up with a way of dealing with tables containing SERIAL fields.

Basically I would like to either somehow create a unique value that I can be reasonably sure will still be unique when I insert a record or at least get the value of a record I just inserted. This must work if many users are using the table at the same time (so a database wide scheme).

I know newer versions have 'sequence' objects that can be set up but SE does not.

Comment: The Informix ODBC driver provides a way to get at the inserted serial number; ESQL/C does too (in the sqlca structure).  Can you get at any of that from C#?  Which version of Informix SE are you using?  Which platform are you using it on?

Comment: I tried this from IBM's website but apparently my version of SE does not support sqcla. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1023.htm

Comment: Actually, I talked to our db guy and it is only supported in unix 4gl/4ge. I am trying to use csharp in windows.

Comment: SE supports `sqlca`; it did when it was first released in 1985 and has done ever since.  However, AFAIK, SE does not support `DBINFO()` at all, much less the `sqlca` parts of `DBINFO()`.  Looking at an Informix (Dynamic Server) manual for information about SE is going to be difficult.  (I'd start at the [SE home page](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/se/).)  Which underlying API is being used by your C# framework; what are you using to establish connections to SE?  A .NET driver?  Or an ODBC driver?  Or something else?

Comment: We use the OdbcConnection object to connect to the database. According to the connection string we are using the {IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER} driver, the sqlexec Service and the sesoctcp Protocol.

Comment: OK, that makes sense — it is probably the best option.  I'm tolerably certain there's a way to get at the last serial value via an ODBC driver, but I don't know exactly what it is.  I'll try and get someone else to tell you and me.  I assume it is Informix SE 7.25.TCx for some numeric value of x (32-bit Windows version), rather than a Unix version running on some other machine (though `sesoctcp` certainly could be a network connection to another machine).  It probably isn't critical, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26199/discussion-between-belmiris-and-jonathan-leffler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: **Informix ODBC driver and .NET Driver do not officially support SE**; it may still work though.
My knowledge about SE is limited too; the information that I list below may more relevant on IDS than SE.

The driver that you are trying is **.NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC**; it does not work well with Informix serial data type.
The **Informix native .NET Provider** has support for serial in IDS, but this driver has never been tested against SE. If you are willing to take risk then chance of getting success may be higher with this.

I don’t think that you have to use any complex algorithm to make serial value unique at server.
The following example will explain it better.

```
    CREATE TABLE tab ( c1 SERIAL );
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 0 ); 
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 4 );  
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 0 ); 
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 3 ); 
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 3 );
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 0 ); 
    SELECT * FROM tab;

     1
     4
     5
     3
     3
     6


DROP TABLE tab;
CREATE TABLE tab ( c1 INT, c2 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 11, 0 );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 12, 0 );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 13, 0 );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 14, 0 );
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( 15, 0 );
SELECT * FROM TAB;

c1          c2

11           1
12           2
13           3
14           4
15           5
```

If you are trying for a serial type value generated at client side such as entries added to DataTable etc then the following properties on **DataColumn** may be useful:
**AutoIncrement**, 
**AutoIncrementStep**,
**AutoIncrementSeed**.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. Unfortunately this shop insists on using a lot of legacy code, including VB6 (this is what I am trying to replace in my spare time). VB6 cannot use 64 bit drivers. The are (finally) planning to upgrade the DBs to IDS but they won't force existing customers to upgrade.

Comment: I think I'm just going to give up and disallow any Inserts for tables that have SERIAL fields in their indexes. Thanks very much for your help.